# Problema al recibir Push Notifications FCM con la app cerrada. Ionic 3 and Angular

Tags: angularjs, nodejs, ionic, firebase, fcm

Buen día gente, es mi primer publicación en el sitio, pido perdón si no cumplo con todas las normas de publicación ya que no las conozco detalladamente.

Paso a comentarles mi problema.. Tengo una app formulada con ionic 3 y angular, la cual trabaja con notificaciones entre usuarios al surgir una acción,
investigue por los foros de firebase y varios otros lugares y probé varios códigos pero no pude solucionarlo.
La aplicación envía datos y notificación a un token especifico, el dispositivo registrado por el token recibe los datos pero no la notificación. Ni cuando esta con la aplicación abierta, ni cuando la tiene en segundo plano o cerrada.
Este es el código que utilice:

**1) Para recibir el token**

```
 this.fcm.getToken().then(token => {

         alert('token' + JSON.stringify(token))

         //Aquí guardo el token que recibo del dispositivo
      })
```

Esto funciona .. puedo obtener el token del dispositivo.

**2) Para recibir la notificación:**

```
this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {  
        if (data.wasTapped) {    
          alert("Received in background")    
        } else {
          alert("Received in foreground")
        };
      })
```

Esto también funciona, **cuando envió una notificación desde la consola de firebase la recibo perfectamente..** el problema es cuando la envió desde el servidor

**3) Codigo para la notificacion:**

```
SendNotific() 
{
   let keytoken = 'fqN5yelN7gk:APA91bGT0......'
   let keyserver = 'AAAA4oCrTNk:APA91bHLBWcyQimF....'    
   let headers = { 'Authorization': 'key='+keyserver,
                   'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
   let url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
   let body = { 
               "notification":{ 
                  "title":"Notification title",
                  "body":"Notification body" 
               },
               "data":{ 
                  "key1": "value1",
                  "key2": "value2" 
               },
               "to" : keytoken,
               "priority": "high",
               "content_available": true 
              }

  this.http.post(url, body, headers).then(data=>
  {
     alert(JSON.stringify(data))

  }).then(error=>{
      alert('error'+JSON.stringify(error))
  })
}
```

**Si la aplicación esta en primer plano del dispositivo**, la alerta se hace visible, es decir recibo los datos que envié en "Data". (Para este caso seria "key1" y "key2") pero no recibo ninguna notificación. 
**Si la aplicación esta en segundo plano o cerrada** no se muestra ninguna notificación, y cuando abro la app nuevamente se muestran los mensajes de alerta con la "Data" que llego..

Como comente antes, **si envió una notificación desde la consola de firebase funciona perfectamente..**

Claramente estoy pasando por alto algún dato que no puedo encontrarlo.. vi varias publicaciones que hablan de lo mismo pero no puedo dar la solución..

¿Me estarán faltando datos específicos dentro de la notificación para que pueda ser visible?

¿Hace falta que el usuario acepte algún permiso para recibir la notificación?

Desde ya muchas gracias y perdón si no supe explicarme con claridad

saludos,

Julián.

Comment: si pudiste solucionar? como lo hiciste por que tengo el mismo inconveniente.

Comment: Si pude!! lo solucione con one signal, es otro plugin como FCM..
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/onesignal/ si buscas sobre el mismo, hay mucha informacion y clara! sino, si necesitas te ayudo, elcodigo es muy parecido al que publique aca

Comment: julian, estoy realizando notificaciones push con onesignal, me funciona y logro enviar a todos los dispositivos notificaciones, quiero enviar a uno en especifico, pero no se como hacerlo, esto lo quiero realizar sin utilizar el dashboard de onesignal, que documentación utilizo?, otra cosa me gustaría identificar al usuario a cual enviar la notificación con un id de usuario en la app ¿como podría hacer eso?.
De antemano gracias!!

Answer (score -1):

Si desde la consola de Firebase puedes enviar notificaciones correctas al dispositivo, el problema seguro que se encuentra en la forma del json que envías a Firebase. Según veo, creo que podrías solucionarlo incluyendo los parámetros title y body también dentro de data. Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Bienvenido FranPino, te sugiero eliminar esta publicación y es importante leer los documentos que te sugieren los usuarios de la comunidad.

Comment: No me funciono, probé como sugeriste agregar dichos parámetros, pero no.. solo llegan como variables al igual que el resto de datos que envié dentro de "data":

Probé también con enviar notificaciones desde el tester de FCM (cordova-plugin-fcm.appspot.com)
y funciona perfectamente.. las notificaciones y datos llegan.. 
Mi problema claramente esta en el json que envió